# jquery clone doesn't seem to retain draggable/droppable events

Tags: jquery, events, clone, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a row where I can drag items into it, and sort them. This all works ok. I even have a delete event on each item, so it can be removed from the row.

I want an option where I can clone the row. I do this by using the clone function below:

```
clonedrow = $("#row1").clone(true);
clonedid = "row"+nextRowNumber; //nextRowNumber is a variable calculated by counting the rows that exist already.
clonedrow.attr("id",clonedid).insertAfter("#row1");
```

This all works, apart from the fact the draggable/sortable events in 'row1' are not copied to the cloned row. Am I doing something wrong? I thought by adding 'true' it copies the events...?

FWIW when loading the page, I have a function which automatically builds the first row, and applies the draggable/sortable/delete events to it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know too much about draggable, but there seems to be some strange behavior when cloning a draggable element with `true`. Perhaps you *don't* want all the `data` cloned if some of it should be specific to that element.

In this simple example, when you `clone(true)` one and try to drag the clone, the original is dragged.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmcHd/

Perhaps it is better to just reapply the `draggable()`.

```
clonedrow = $("#row1").clone().draggable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmcHd/1/

If there are other settings that you need, then I'd store them in a variable in order to prevent duplication.

```
var settings = {
        // some settings
}

clonedrow = $("#row1").clone().draggable(settings);
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick! This has helped a lot :) I don't suppose you could have a look at another query I have? Would be much appreciated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549631/jquery-strange-behaviour-when-toggling-hiding-showing-droppable-panels

Comment: @WastedSpace - You're welcome. I'd be happy to take a look at the other one, but I can't right now. I'll check back a little later. :o)

Comment: @WastedSpace - Sorry, took a look at the other. Not sure what the cause of the problem would be. Afraid I won't be much help. :o(

Comment: OK, no problem. Thanks for taking a look anyway. It's really weird, as I also found 2 other people's examples of drag & drop panels (to resemble the google home page), and they have exactly the same issues... back to the drawing board I guess...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery copy events and data if clone is passed true parameter. In order to test whether events have been passed see events property of element's data http://www.jsfiddle.net/zfSrR/1/

```
console.log($("#row1").data('events'));
console.log($(clonedrow).data('events'));
```

Comment: Ayaz - You can't use `.live()` to apply plugin behavior. Only DOM events. :o)